# Why isn't Collections.binarySearch() working with this comparable?

Tags: java, generics, collections, binary-search, comparable

I have this `Player` class which implements the `Comparable` interface. Then I have an `ArrayList` of `Player`s. I'm trying to use `binarySearch()` on the list of `Player`s to find one `Player`, but Java is giving me a "`cannot find symbol: method binarySearch(java.util.ArrayList< Player>,Player)`".

This the Player class:

```
class Player implements Comparable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    Statistics stats;

    //Constructor, creates a new Player with a supplied username
    Player(String name) {
        username = name;
        password = "";
        stats = new Statistics();
    }

    //Accessor method to return the username as a String
    String getName() {
        return username;
    }

    String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    void setPassword(String newPass) {
        password = newPass;
    }

    //Method to change the username
    void setName(String newName) {
        username = newName;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return username.compareTo(((Player)o).username);
    }
}
```

Weird thing, when I try Collections.sort() on this same list, it works.

Comment: Can you show us the code that invokes Collections.binarySearch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use are using generics inconsistently. Take heed of the compiler warnings. Always supply generic arguments (or never supply them).

Instead of:

```
class Player implements Comparable {
    [...]
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
```

Use

```
class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
    [...]
    public int compareTo(Player o) {
```

The rules of generics are difficult enough without the complication of rare types. So, typically the language spec gives up if you mix them up.

Comment: wow this fixed the problem. Thanks. I must've missed that part in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are implementing [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), you can make `compareTo()` consistent with `equals()` by also overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`. This is particularly easy in this case, as you can simply delegate to `String`. Moreover, it's convenient if you ever need a `Map` containing instances of `Player`:

```
class Player implements Comparable<String> {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    // ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(String name) {
        return username.compareTo(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Player
            && username.equals(((Player)obj).username);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return username.hashCode();
    }
}
```