# Avoid duplicates to be added to List using equals and hashcode

Tags: java

I have two objects as Employee and Person. Both of them have firstName and lastName.
I don't want to add object(either Employee or Person) to the list if firstName,lastName for either Person and Employee has already been added to the list.

Use equals and hashcode to do this...

Edit:I cannot use Set or any other collection, and have to use equals and hashcode to achieve this.

Comment: You need to attempt this yourself first, then come back with any code issues.

Comment: Why do you require to use equals and hashcode? Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For equals/hashcode example you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066917/overriding-equals-hashcode-in-sub-classes-considering-super-fields). As for adding to List, there are two options:

1. Check if List contains the object with [List.contains method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) every time before you add an element to it
2. Use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which will save the order of added elements and then return `new ArrayList<Employee>(employeeLinkedHashSet);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to couple the identities of `Employee` and `Person`, this can't be achieved trivially, except if you are prepared to

1. have `Employee extends Person` and
2. have all `Employees` equal as soon as they equal as `Person`s, regardless of any further properties they may have.

If these constraints are acceptable to you, then just implement `Person#equals` and `Person#hashCode` to involve `firstName` and `lastName` and use a `Set` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I think I can have Employee extend Person,but I shouldn't allow duplicates in the list using equals and hashcode.Thats my question.

Comment: Excellent; then proceed as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [set](/questions/tagged/set) [interface](/questions/tagged/interface) to avoid duplicates [read more in the Java API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a `List` that wraps an existing `List` implementation like `ArrayList`
2. Delegate all method calls to the wrapped list
3. Implement `add` and `addAll` so that they do not add the values if they're already in the list.

Note, that this implementation would be inconsistant with the `List` interface, because user expect that a call to `add` *really* adds the object to the collection (size increases by one).

It would be much better to either use a `Set` implementation (avoids duplicates but does not preserve insertion order) or check for duplicates *before* you add:

```
 List<Person> persons = getPersonsFromSomewhere();
 Person person = getAPersonThatShallBeAddedIfNotDuplicate();
 if (!persons.contains(person)) {
    persons.add(person);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` and not a list. If you need a list you can call `Set.toArray()` and pass that to a `List` constructor.

Have you Employee and Person classes implement `Comparable<T>`. Making Employee a subclass of Person might make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should be using a map if your have some fields which should be unique.  You can use a custom class which is a compound key, or you can combine the Strings into a single string using a seperator.

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = ....

String fullname = employee.firstName + "~" + employee.lastName;
Employee employee = employeeMap.get(fullname);
if (employee == null) {
   // not in the map so add it.
   employeeMap.put(fullname, employee);
} else {
   // employee is already in the collection.
   // alter it or produce a warning
}
```

Note: String already has `equals` and `hashCode` methods so you don't need to add them.