# Why is NetBean's autogenerated equals so verbose?

Tags: java, netbeans

When NetBeans autogenerates an `equals` method it is in the following form:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    final MyClass other = (MyClass)obj;
    if (!Object.equals(this.field, other.field))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This seems quite verbose. Java's `instanceof` returns `false` for `null` values so why not simplify the initial tests to:

```
if (!(obj instanceof MyClass))
    return false;
```

I'm also unclear on why this code would explicitly use `this.field` in the field comparisons (presumably to avoid confusion) but then wouldn't use `this.getClass()` for the same reason?

Are there any advantages at all to NetBean's form?

Comment: It's probably provided to allow you to define entry points into your implementation

Comment: @MadProgrammer To be honest I normally write the implementation myself. I posted the question to see if anyone could come up with a rational explanation for the autogenerated code.

Comment: I tend to use a combination of it and Apache Commons :P

Answer (score 4):

There's a **big** difference between `instanceof` and class comparison. Remember that (for example) a `HashMap` instance is `instanceof` `AbstractMap`, but `AbstractMap`'s `equals` shouldn't consider `other` an `AbstractMap` if it's actually a `HashMap`. `instanceof` tests allow for an instance of the type *or any of its subtypes* and are therefore not symmetric. `equals` requires symmetry. (Example below.)

The Netbeans code does seem rather stilted and could be written more concisely, but the operations, in the order given, make sense as a default starting point. (Although I'd've included a `this` check.) It's a rare pair of classes that can have usefully have `equal` instances, so using `getClass` for a default implementation is reasonable.

Just to remind us all of [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

- It is *reflexive*: for any non-`null` reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
- It is *symmetric*: for any non-`null` reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.
- It is *transitive*: for any non-`null` reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
- It is *consistent*: for any non-`null` reference values `x and`y`, multiple invocations of`x.equals(y)`consistently return`true`or consistently return`false`, provided no information used in`equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.
- For any non-`null` reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

In my early Java days in the 90's I broke this contract (unwittingly), and [based on the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066917/overriding-equals-hashcode-in-sub-classes-considering-super-fields), I'm not the only one. I used `instanceof` (and `super.equals`), like this:

```
class Parent {
    private int foo;
    protected int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    Parent(int f) {
        this.foo = f;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // WRONG, see below
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Parent)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.foo == ((Parent)obj).foo;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    private int bar;

    Child(int f, int b) {
        super(f);
        this.bar = b;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // WRONG, see below
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Child)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.equals(obj) && this.bar == ((Child)obj).bar;
    }
}
```

The problem there is that it's not symmetric:

```
Parent p = new Parent(1);
Child  c = new Child(1, 2);
System.out.println(p.equals(c)); // true
System.out.println(c.equals(p)); // false
```

That violates the contract.

Comment: Actually objects of different types **can** be equal according to the `equals()` contract, rare as it would be.

Comment: @Kayaman: I'll have to take your word for it, but it would be a rare case regardless. I've reworded slightly.